# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' despite installation

Tags: python, opencv

When I import `cv2` in Python I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
```

I installed `cv2` with

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

When I try to install it again, it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (4.0.1.24)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from opencv-python) (1.16.2)
```

I successfully double-checked if package is available in the appropriate Python folder. I even installed it for Python2.7 though Python3.7 is my standard. I literally read through all information I could find on Stackoverflow regarding the error and I am run out of ideas now. Any ideas?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing with your OS's package manager (notice the word order: `python` before `opencv`):

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

This worked for me on Ubuntu 18. I also was unable to get it to work using `pip`.

Comment: I did but still face the problem. Did you remove the opencv pip package?

Comment: No I didn’t, but you could try to uninstall the ones you installed earlier with `pip`. When you tried using the package after the apt-get install, which version of Python did you use? The command in my post will be for Python 2.x version. You can install `python3-opencv` for py3