# Opencv is installed in my machine, But cannot import in my python project

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, opencv3.0

I have installed openCV in my machine I am using ubuntu 16.04 but cannot import opencv.

when importing opencv in my python project I receive this error....

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zubad/Documents/check/newProject/check.py", line 5, in 
    import cv2 as cv
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'

opencv is successfully installed and i can also check the version

import cv2 as cv
print(cv.__version)

Comment: Is your project running on virtual environment by any chance? virtualenv/pipenv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' despite installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55603463/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-cv2-despite-installation)

Comment: Did you check any of these? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+install+import+python+ubuntu+is%3Aq